# Git: `refspec XXXXXXXX does not match any.` While pushing some changes after some commits

Tags: git

Doing `git status` shows me

```
On branch ashwini-rr
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/ashwini-rate-recommendations' by 8 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

but doing `git push origin ashwini-rate-recommendations` show me the following error:

```
error: src refspec ashwini-rate-recommendations does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:xxxxx/xxxxx.git'
```

Running `git show-ref` shows something like as below:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXX refs/heads/ashwini-rr
XXXXXXXXXXXX refs/heads/dbv
XXXXXXXXXXXX refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
XXXXXXXXXXXX refs/remotes/origin/ashwini-rate-recommendations
```

`git --version` gives me `git version 2.3.2 (Apple Git-55)`

`push.default=matching`

I am unable to figure out why this is causing `error: src refspec ashwini-rate-recommendations does not match any.` even when it is not the case of a first commit. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried pulling first before pushing?

Comment: yes... pulling works flawlessly...

Comment: sorry, but that's the case where user had not committed even a single time... My case there are already few commits still it causes the same error... (Even the pull / status / branch -vv all are working fine as expected)

Comment: @TheGeorgeous :- Being explicitly said in the question that "the push has been attempted after  few commits", this question is no where duplicate to the question you are referring me to. Please reconsider your vote to close the question.

Comment: @TheGeorgeous :- Hey.... if you are sort of agree with what I commented above, can you please remove the vote for closing the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your local branch is named ashwini-rr and you are pushing it ashwini-rate-recommendations.

Try running:

```
git push origin ashwini-rr:ashwini-rate-recommendations.
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need, is to tell git what to push at the ashwini-rate-recommendations branch :

```
git push origin ashwini-rr:ashwini-rate-recommendations
```

Or, since the branch is tracked, simply :

```
git push
```

Comment: how do I test if the branch is tracked.. and by this did you just mean that 'upstream is set for this branch'